# Till what stage do I have to return errors in Go?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using Go and Gin Gonic to test and exercise some basics in Go. I first did some syntax and basis exercising already.

I've a `main.go` (using Gin Gonic) in which I define paths like `r.GET(/todo, handler)`. I've a `hander.go` in which I describe the handlers like this:

```
func GetTodoListHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, todo.Get())
}
```

At last I have some `todo/todo.go` where I define my todo struct and functions.

Now my question, till what stage do I have to return errors?

In my `todo/todo.go` I have the `Get()` function. It uses another helper function which can have a possible error e.g.

```
location, err := helper(blabla)
if err != nil {
    // for a pointer we can return a nil
    return nil, err
}
```

Now should I return the possible error from the helper function to the `Get` function and from the get function back to the `handler` function or not? Till what stage do I have to return these errors, is it always till the handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
func GetTodoListHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    list, err := todo.Get()
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, list)
}
```

and have `todo.Get` return (list, error).

Your http handlers, like `GetTodoListHandler`, should never return the errors, but send responses/status codes to the client.

Comment: Thanks so you would return errors from functions till the handlers?

Comment: It might be a good rule of thumb to start out, but in the end you need to decide what you want to do with the errors.

Comment: So it is okay to check for errors in the function (e.g. Get()) log and return them to the handler and check there again?